# What is the time complexity for this code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the time complexity T(n) for the following algorithm?
where the array A is indexed 1 through n.

```
     int add_them ( int n , int A[ ] ) { 
          index i , j , k ;
          j= 0 ;
          for ( i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
                 j = j + A[i]; 
          k = 1;
          for ( i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++) 
                  k =k +k ;
           return j + k ; 
}
```

first loop = n 
second loop = n

T(n) = n + n = 2n = O(n)

im not sure if my answer is correct

Comment: The result of this function is much larger than the inputs (k is 2^n by the end), so although you correctly count arithmetic operations, it's important whether you consider arithmetic on arbitrarily large integers to be O(1) or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct, the time complexity of the algorithm is O(n).

The first loop iterates n times and has a time complexity of O(n).

The second loop also iterates n time and it also has a time complexity of O(n).

Finally, adding j and k requires a constant amount of time, so it does not affect the overall time complexity. Thus, the total time complexity is the sum of the time complexities of the two loops, which is O(n) + O(n) = O(2n) = O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

Keep in mind that 2 consecutive loops (that are not nested) won't necessarily make it O(n^2). Only if they are nested.

Ofcourse there are exceptions to this ^